Evaluating $I=\int_1^\infty \frac{2(z^2-1)}{(z^2+1)^2\ln(z)}\,dz$
$$
I =
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh\left(x\right)\operatorname{sech}\left(x\right)}{x}\,{\rm d}x
$$
I started with the substitution $\cosh x=t \implies [0,\infty] \to[1,\infty]$
$$I=\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t^2 \ln(t+\sqrt{t^2-1})}\,dt$$
then the  substitution $t+\sqrt{t^2-1}=z\implies [1,\infty] \to[1,\infty]$
$$I=\int_1^\infty \frac{2(z^2-1)}{(z^2+1)^2\ln(z)}\,dz$$
I am stuck on this integral and I have tried some more substitutions but they seem to make the integral harder to evaluate, I am interested to see how to solve this.

It seems no elementary antiderivative exists.

This integral can be done with residue theorem, write $\frac{\tanh(x) \text{sech}(x)}{x}$ as $\frac{\sinh(x)}{x\cosh^{2}(x)}$. Since the integral is even, then you can extend the limit over $R$, choose poles are $(2k+1)\frac{i\pi}{2}$ where $k\ge 0$. The residue is $\frac{-(-1)^k4i}{\pi^2(2k+1)^2}$. Taking sum from $k=0$ to $\infty$ you get $-\frac{4iG}{\pi^2}$, where $G$ is the Catalan constant. The result of the given integral equals $\frac{1}{2}2\pi i \left(-\frac{4iG}{\pi^2}\right)=\frac{4G}{\pi}$

Let $J(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{z^{a+1}}{(1+z^2)^2\ln z}dz$. Then
$$J’(a) = \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{a+1}}{(1+t^2)^2}
dt\overset{ibp}
=-\frac a2 \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{a+1}}{1+t^2}dt
=\frac{\pi a}{4}\csc\frac{\pi a}2 $$
and
$$I=\int_1^\infty \frac{2(z^2-1)}{(z^2+1)^2\ln z}\,dz
=\int_0^\infty \frac{z^2-1}{(z^2+1)^2\ln z}\,dz$$
$$=\int_{-1}^{1}J’(a)da
\overset{t=\tan\frac {\pi a}4} =\frac 4\pi \int_0^{1}\frac {\tan^{-1}t}{t}dt
=\frac{4}{\pi}G
\\
$$

Could you explain this step $I=\int_1^\infty \frac{2(z^2-1)}{(z^2+1)^2\ln z},dz
=\int_0^\infty \frac{z^2-1}{(z^2+1)^2\ln z},dz$

@whatamidoing Note that $$\int_1^\infty \frac{z^2-1}{(z^2+1)^2\ln z},dz
\overset{z\to \frac1z}=\int_0^1\frac{z^2-1}{(z^2+1)^2\ln z},dz$$

@whatamidoing Right, but joining $\int_0^1+\int_1^\infty$ gives you...

@user170231, thank you very much, i lost track of that step

As @Quanto noticed that
$$
I \stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}}{=}  \int_0^1 \frac{2\left(z^2-1\right)}{\left(1+z^2\right)^2 \ln z} d z,
$$
we have
$$
I=\int_0^1+\int_1^{\infty}=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{z^2-1}{\left(1+z^2\right)^2 \ln z} d z.
$$
Noticing that
$$
\frac{z^2-1}{\ln z}=\int_{-1}^1 z^{y+1} d y,
$$
we can re-write the integral into a double integral $$
I=\int_{-1}^1 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{z^{y+1}}{\left(1+z^2\right)^2} d z d y.
$$
We now let $z=\tan \theta$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{z^{y+1}}{\left(1+z^2\right)^2} d z =& \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{y+1} \theta \cos ^{1-y} \theta d \theta \\
= & \frac{1}{2} B\left(\frac{y}{2}+1, 1-\frac{y}{2}\right) \\
= & \frac{1}{2} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{y}{2}+1\right) \Gamma\left(1-\frac{y}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(2)} \\
= & \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{y}{2} \cdot \Gamma\left(\frac{y}{2}\right) \Gamma\left(1-\frac{y}{2}\right) \\
= & \frac{\pi}{4} y \csc \frac{\pi y}{2} \quad \textrm{( By the reflection property of Gamma function)}
\end{aligned}
$$
Plugging back yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{\pi}{4} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{y}{\sin \left(\frac{\pi y}{2}\right)} d y \\
& =\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{y}{\sin \left(\frac{\pi y}{2}\right)} d y \\
& =\frac{8}{\pi} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{z}{\sin (2 z)} d z \text {, where } z=\frac{\pi y}{4} \\
& =\frac{4}{\pi} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} z \,d(\ln (\tan z)) \\
& =-\frac{4}{\pi} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (\tan z) d z \quad \textrm{ (Via integration by parts)} \\
& =-\frac{4}{\pi}(-G) \cdots (*)\\
& =\frac{4 G}{\pi}
\end{aligned}
$$
where (*) using the result in the post.
